# Importing GSON using dependencies not giving access to methods

Tags: android, android-studio, gson, android-gradle-plugin

I have imported GSON by adding a line to the dependencies section in my module's build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.project"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
}
```

I can see the Gson files under my applications external libraries and go through all of the files. The issue is that when I try and use a Gson object I only get access to ".class". I can open the Gson library and see all of the methods (see image below) available but my compiler is not finding them. I have tried rebuilding, closing and reopening Android Studio, and removing and adding the library. I am new to using this fancy maven dependencies stuff so maybe I am missing something?

[image]

I am trying to learn how to use the gradle/maven to handle my decencies instead of downloading and including .jar files as I feel this is the more modern and standard way of including libraries. Can someone let me know if this is true or if downloading and including libraries via libs/library.jar is used just as much?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Here is a screen shot of what I mean when I say I only get access to ".class" when trying to use the Gson object.

[image]

Comment: Follow this [tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/getting-started-with-google-gson.html)

Comment: Hey Harry, that is actually the tutorial that I followed to get to where I am. As you can see from my gradle file I have the dependency line as well we the repository block. The problem is that when I am writing "Gson." I only see "class" and no methods. However, I can see the full Gson library and all of its files/methods by opening the files as seen in my image above.

Comment: configure jcentre and mavencentral properly, you have missed some of the dependencies in gradle

Comment: Got it, I ended up closing everything restarting once again and created a Gson object. Everything seems to be working now, not sure if anything was wrong or if it was just user error as it seems like I didn't change anything. Thanks!

Comment: You need to init object like Gson gson = new Gson(); then you will get methods by gson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to use the `Gson` object you need an instance of `Gson` for example

```
Object someObject = new Object();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(someObject);
```